# Domain configured through Amazon Route 53 not working

Tags: amazon-route53

I configured Route 53 for my aws ec2 instance.

I can access my Tomcat server hosted in ec2 instance through elastic IP. It works.

But it's been more than 48hours I configured domain name in route 53 using my elastic ip, but still I am not able to access through my domain name `www.wcam.com:8080`.

> My instance ID : i-773eeaaf
>
> Elastic IP : 52.25.251.3
>
> Public DNS : ec2-52-25-251-3.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

I use to access my application in aws like this

> ec2-52-25-251-3.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080

or

> 52.25.251.3:8080

and I wanted to access like this www.wcam.com:8080 (which is not working).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like wcam.com is delegated to Route 53 [1].  You will need to update your registrar to delegate wcam.com to Route 53.

1. http://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=www.wcam.com&type=&trace=on&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=